# SWF file decompiling program

Tags: flash

I have decompiled an swf file in to .fla file by using a registered decompiling software, in that fla file there is code "getURL("./home.html", "_self");" , but when i run this file getting the following error.

> The currently targeted Flash Player does not support the getURL action.

How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

getURL is a function of Flash Player 2 to 8. Sounds like you are then trying to compile for Flash Player 9 or above.